# Add name and value to data attribute array with attr()

Tags: jquery, attr, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to build and array inside a data attribute but I'm getting [object, object] when I try to add the name and value

```
<div class="wrapper"></div>

$post_url = "http://example.ai";
$post_id = "750";
$(".wrapper").attr("data-history", {
  id: $post_id,
  url: $post_url
});
```

I'm first creating the data attribute "history" but then it adds [object, object] to it. After this I need to add another name/value to the "history" array on the next event.

Comment: <div class="wrapper"></div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues, one is that you should not have the dot(.) in the class attribute and two you have to add the attribute as JSON (or use `.data`, depending on how you want to use the attribute)

```
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

```
$post_url = "http://example.ai";
$post_id = "750";
$(".wrapper").attr("data-history", JSON.strinify({
  id: $post_id,
  url: $post_url
}));
```

or

```
$post_url = "http://example.ai";
$post_id = "750";
$(".wrapper").data("history", {
  id: $post_id,
  url: $post_url
});
```

EDIT:

To add new items just get the old data and add the new data to it

```
$post_url = "http://example.ai";
$post_id = "750";
var data = $(".wrapper").attr("data-history");
if (!data){
    data = [];
}
else{
    data = JSON.parse(data);
}
data.push({
  id: $post_id,
  url: $post_url
});
$(".wrapper").attr("data-history", JSON.strinify(data));
```

or

```
$post_url = "http://example.ai";
$post_id = "750";
var data = $(".wrapper").data("history");
if (!data){
    data = [{
        id: $post_id,
        url: $post_url
    }];
}
else{
    data.push({
        id: $post_id,
        url: $post_url
    });
}    
$(".wrapper").data("history", data);
```

Comment: Yeah stringify works. But how to add another name/value to what we just added? I'm building the array on each event. The next one replaces what we added.